# mysql: query to return scores ranks according to a specific user

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Lets say i have the following scores table (total rows of 10):

```
rank userid score
---- ------ -----
 1   |455   |10
 2   |435   |9
 3   |354   |8
 4   |342   |7
 5   |343   |6
 6   |123   |5
 7   |125   |4
 8   |128   |3
 9   |5     |2
10   |6     |1
```

the user can fetch his score status, and he can get 5 score positions around his position.
which means:

1. if the user is at 1st place, he will get the results of ranks 1-5
2. if the user is at 6th place, he will get the results of ranks 4-9
3. if the user is at 9th place, he will get the results of rank 6-10

I'm trying to find the most optimized method to perform these operations to get the score status for the user only in SQL, no other language integration.

thanks alot!!!

## update

this table is actually created on-the-fly

i have a game_log table with gameid, userid and time and logid (which is playid)
and i have game_score table with logid and score.

i use the following query:

```
@rank:=0;

select @rank:=@rank+1 as rank,userid,score from (
select * from (
   select game_log_gameid as gameid,
   game_log_userid as userid,
(select max(game_score_log_score)
        from game_score_log where game_score_log_logid=game_log_id) as score,
        (select game_score_log_timestamp as time from
            game_score_log where game_score_log_logid=game_log_id and
            game_score_log_score = score order by game_score_log_timestamp desc)
            as time from game_log
where game_log_gameid=620
order by score desc,time
) as a group by gameid,userid ) as b order by score desc,time
```

Comment: How much of the above table is dynamically produced via the query? i.e.: Is there really a 'rank' field in the table or is this produced on the fly?

Comment: the rank is produced on the fly. i will edit the main post to add that information

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it makes a great deal of sense to attempt to do all of this in a single query, as you'd require a sub-select or something similar to obtain the user's rank which you could then calculate the limits around.

As such, it might make more sense to obtain the user's rank with a single query, calculate the limits you want to obtain in your source programming language (handling edge cases will be a lot easier here than in SQL) and then issue a simply query that uses [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to obtain the required data.

For example, once you've computed 'startRank' as above, you'd simply use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE rank >= startRank ORDER BY rank ASC LIMIT 5;
```

---

**Update**: This doesn't make quite as much sense now that you've revealed that rank is dynamically calculated, but the general point I was making is still valid - handling edge cases such as initial & final positions will be a lot easier in a programming language than in SQL.

Comment: actually i'm already using the solution you provided here. i calculate the rank of the user first and then i fetch the relevant rows. i was trying to find out if there is a more optimized way.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the resultant SQL wasn't so torturous as to be a maintenance nightmare if you need to tweak things further down the line. That said, hopefully someone out there will prove otherwise. :-)

Comment: I know that it will be easier to do so in a programming language then in mysql, the problem is that in order for me to do so i'll need to fetch all the rows to calculate them and it may be a very long table.